# Where is defined nil in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, null

I would like to know there is defined the `nil` object in Ruby MRI programming language. It looks like a constant, but unlike a constant it is not in upcase style.

There is also the NilClass which is a class. But where is defined `nil`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined in [*keyword.rb*](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000026) file :

> A special "non-object". `nil` is, in fact, an object (the sole instance of `NilClass`), but *connotes absence and indeterminacy*. `nil` and `false` are the only two objects in Ruby that have **Boolean falsehood** (informally, that cause an `if` condition to fail).
>
> `nil` serves as the default value for uninitialized array elements and hash values (unless the default is overridden)

From the Ruby officials - [Keywords](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/eeb05e8c119f8cab6434d90f21551b6bb2954778/doc/keywords.rdoc#keywords) and [*keyword_nil*](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L1985).

Answer (score 2):

`nil` is a keyword, like `def`, `if`, `class`, `and`, `or`, `end`, etc. Keywords are defined in the parser.